# Cannot operate one directory with proper permissions set

Tags: linux, kubernetes, github-actions

I'm use GitHub actions runner controller to deploy self-hosted runner in our Kubernetes cluster, but now it fail with the following error:

```
Error: Error: Missing file at path: /runner/_work/_temp/_runner_hook_responses/2ee89e97-2fec-446b-bf18-06e0843fb51a.json
```

I managed to add some sleep in the runner pod, then I exec'ed into the pod during job running, found something interesting:

```
runner@arc-demo-rd-zzv72-l7rc4:/runner$ ls -aln
total 104
drwxrwsrwx. 9 1000 1001  4096 Jun 14 23:59 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1    0    0  4096 Jun 14 23:59 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1001   263 Jun 14 23:59 .credentials
-rw-------. 1 1000 1001  1667 Jun 14 23:59 .credentials_rsaparams
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1001     0 Jun 14 23:59 .env
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1001    86 Jun 14 23:59 .path
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1001   391 Jun 14 23:59 .runner
drwxr-sr-x. 4 1000 1001  4096 Jun 14 23:59 _diag
drwxrwsr-x. 7 1000 1000  4096 Jun 14 23:59 _work
drwxrwsr-x. 2 1000 1000  4096 Jun 14 23:59 _work1
drwxr-sr-x. 4 1000 1001 16384 Jun 14 23:59 bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001  2458 Jun 14 23:59 config.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001   646 Jun 14 23:59 env.sh
drwxr-sr-x. 6 1000 1001  4096 Jun 14 23:59 externals
drwxr-sr-x. 2 1000 1001  4096 Jun 14 23:59 externalstmp
drwxr-sr-x. 2 1000 1001  4096 Jun 14 23:59 k8s
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1001  1487 Jun 14 23:59 run-helper.cmd.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001  2522 Jun 14 23:59 run-helper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001  2522 Jun 14 23:59 run-helper.sh.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001  2537 Jun 14 23:59 run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001    65 Jun 14 23:59 safe_sleep.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1001  5232 Jun 14 23:59 svc.sh
runner@arc-demo-rd-zzv72-l7rc4:/runner$ cd _work1
runner@arc-demo-rd-zzv72-l7rc4:/runner/_work1$ cd ..
runner@arc-demo-rd-zzv72-l7rc4:/runner$ cd _work
bash: cd: _work: Permission denied
```

`_work` is the working directory of the job, I think the runner process cannot operate it, and I cannot do anything with it too, "ls", "cd", "chmod", "chgrp", with or without sudo.

Any reason for the difference between `_work` and `_work1`? The later is created manually and everything looks good with it.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the `_work1` directory was created manually and everything looks good with it. If it serves the same purpose as the `_work` directory, you could try using `_work1` instead and see if the runner process can operate on it successfully. Make sure to update the necessary configurations to reflect this change.

Remember to restart the runner after making any modifications to ensure the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be the problem with volume mount, we're using ReadWriteOnce volume for the runner pod, in most cases ReadWriteOnce volume should not and cannot be mounted to more than 1 pod at a time, but looks like Actions Runner Controller ignored this field and mount the work volume to both the runner pod and the job pod, once after the job pod start, the runner pod lost access to the volume / directory.

I fixed the issue with ReadWriteMany volume, I think it's a bug for Actions Runner Controller.